# Automatically receive files via Bluetooth on windows XP

Tags: bluetooth, windows-xp, file-transfer, obex

I read many many posts to solve this issue but I didn't succeed till now! Any help is highly appreciated!
I have an android application running on a Smartphone which allows the user to shoot pictures and add some exif tags to the resulting jpg.These pictures are all saved in the same folder.
As soon as the Smartphone can connect via bluetooth to a PC (windows XP embedded) the application should send them to the PC. 
The best solution to send the pictures is to use the Android support application for file transfer using OBEX protocol (it can be called via Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND) ).

My problem is to automatically receive the files I'm sending from the Smartphone.
Now I can perform this by always put the PC in "receive file" mode from the bluetooth icon menu on the taskbar (right click -> Receive file) and then confirm where to save the file. But I have to do everything by hand.

Is there a way to automatically receive the files and save them in the desired folder??
Can I achieve this by using another BT stack??

The alternative I can figure out is to implement an application also on the PC and implement my own protocol with raw data exchange on a serial port over bluetooth. (but of course this would be a bad workaround!!!)

It seems almost impossible but there shoud be a good way to solve this! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not fixed on Bluetooth, have a look at my Open Source project http://cross-copy.net.

It simplifies inter-device file transfer between apps: connection is made through a sever by matching codewords. The RESTful API is very simple and you could easily modify the web-app to start download as soon as the file arrives.

Comment: Hi Rodja, thank for your reply!  Actually I won't have internet connection on the devices thus your solution is not applicable to my case!